# Rails form submission by AJAX with an active storage attachment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-activestorage

I have a form that I want to submit using AJAX. The form lets you upload a picture as an attachment, among other fields. Now using pure rails it works just fine, and the AJAX post function I have set up also works...until I try to upload this image file. It just submits without the file as if I did not attach it. What is the correct flow for this? the ajax function

```
function postInstrument() {
  $("form#new_instrument").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: `http://localhost:3000/users/${userId}/instruments`,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
      success: document.getElementById("new-instrument-form-div").innerHTML = 'Instrument Added!'
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: what function did you use with AJAX ? did you convert to base64? Please post some code as it will help us answer your question

Comment: added my ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just to wrap my form in a `FormData` object.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: For anyone still wondering how to do this just type:
 

```const formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0])```


and use ```formData``` as the `$.ajax` `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are using .serialize for your image data. And that is not possible.
This link is by far the best for you to read about file uploading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

```
function FileUpload(img, file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();  
  this.ctrl = createThrobber(img);
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  this.xhr = xhr;

  const self = this;
  this.xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          const percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
          self.ctrl.update(percentage);
        }
      }, false);

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e){
          self.ctrl.update(100);
          const canvas = self.ctrl.ctx.canvas;
          canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
      }, false);
  xhr.open("POST", "http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/paul/demos/resources/webservices/devnull.php");
  xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    xhr.send(evt.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

And here [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously/8758614#8758614)

Comment: Thanks so much for replying I hope this helps. Gonna get a coffee and get to reading.